# How to use my own root certificate in iOS Secure Transport API?

Tags: ios, security, ssl

I'm trying to use [Apple's Secure Transport API](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Reference/secureTransportRef/) on top of an established transport layer, with my own root certificate.  I have my root certificate as a `SecCertificateRef`, but I can't figure out how to make it trusted.

I've examined the following functions, each of which seems tantalizingly close to what I need:

- `SSLAddDistinguishedName()` is unimplemented;
- `SSLSetTrustedRoots()` is deprecated;
- `SSLSetCertificateAuthorities()` is for client authentication only.

If I could override the `SecTrustRef` within the `SecContextRef`, then `SecTrustSetAnchorCertificates()` would do the job.  Unfortunately, this avenue only led me to `SSLGetPeerSecTrust()` which seems to be an Apple-private API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is the following:

```
OSStatus status = SSLSetSessionOption(sslContext, kSSLSessionOptionBreakOnServerAuth, true);
```

and then later during the handshake

```
 OSStatus status = SSLHandshake(sslContext);
    if (status == errSSLPeerAuthCompleted)
    {
        SecTrustRef trust = NULL;
        status = SSLCopyPeerTrust(sslContext, &trust);

        // Perform your custom trust rules here.  e.g.
        BOOL bTrusted = NO;
        NSArray* anchor = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(id)pCACert];
        OSStatus result = SecTrustSetAnchorCertificates(trust, (CFArrayRef)anchor);
        /* Uncomment this to enable both system certs and the one we are supplying */
        //result = SecTrustSetAnchorCertificatesOnly(trust, NO);
        SecTrustResultType trustResult;
        result = SecTrustEvaluate(trust, &trustResult);
        if (result == errSecSuccess)
        {
          switch (trustResult)
          {
            case kSecTrustResultProceed:
            case kSecTrustResultUnspecified:
              bTrusted = YES;
              break;

            case kSecTrustResultInvalid:
            case kSecTrustResultDeny:
            case kSecTrustResultRecoverableTrustFailure:
            case kSecTrustResultFatalTrustFailure:
            case kSecTrustResultOtherError:
            default:
              break;
          }
        }

        // If trusted, continue the handshake
        if (bTrusted)
          status = SSLHandshake(sslContext);
        else 
        {
          /* Your trust failure handling here ~ disconnect */
        }
    }
```

where pCAcert is the root certificate (SecCertificateRef) you wish to trust

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this you are trying to:

{your app} --[ssl session]--> {your server}

Your server is using some certificate signed by your own CA (root). You're trying to ship your CA cert with your phone and use that as the trusted CA instead of the global CAs that are out there.

This seems to be what you're looking for:

> Preparing for a session
>
> 1. Call SSLNewContext (in OS X) or SSLCreateContext (in iOS and OS X) to
>      create a new SSL session context.
> 2. Write the SSLWrite andSSLRead I/O functions and call SSLSetIOFuncs to
>      pass them to Secure Transport.
> 3. Establish a connection using CFNetwork, BSD Sockets, or Open
>      Transport. Then call SSLSetConnection to specify the connection to
>      which the SSL session context applies.
> 4. Call SSLSetPeerDomainName to specify the fully-qualified domain name
>      of the peer to which you want to connect (optional but highly
>      recommended).
> 5. Call **SSLSetCertificate** to specify the certificate to be used in
>      authentication (required for server side, optional for client).

```
OSStatus SSLSetCertificate ( SSLContextRef context, CFArrayRef certRefs );
```

**certRefs**
The certificates to set. This array contains items of type SecCertificateRef, except for certRefs[0], which is of type SecIdentityRef.

> Discussion Setting the certificate or certificates is mandatory for
>   server connections, but is optional for clients. Specifying a
>   certificate for a client enables SSL client-side authentication. You
>   must place in certRefs[0] a SecIdentityRef object that identifies the
>   leaf certificate and its corresponding private key. **Specifying a root
>   certificate is optional;** if it’s not specified, the root certificate
>   that verifies the certificate chain specified here must be present in
>   the system wide set of trusted anchor certificates.

from: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Reference/secureTransportRef/

Comment: I believe the purpose of `SSLSetCertificate()` is to let a device communicate its identity and certificate chain to the other device.  I'm looking for a way for the client to specify that it trusts a certain root certificate.  I'll give your suggestion a try, but I don't think it's what I'm looking for.

Comment: I added emphasis on the part that says you can override the root certs from the device.

Comment: Has this actually worked for anyone if they aren't interested in a client cert? I tried doing this and still get `CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9810)`. You can't specify a null `certRefs[0]` and if I try to just put a random cert in there it doesn't work either.